# 403 error on installing SuiteCRM

Tags: http, sugarcrm, http-status-code-403, suitecrm

I've got **`403 Forbidden`** error while installing SuiteCRM on shared hosting in the phase where you need to enter database credentials.

On a console, there's a report **`403 (Forbidden)`** on file **`/cache/include/javascript/sugar_grp1_yui.js`** which leads to **`YAHOO is not defined`** error and makes installation unable continue.

**Full error when accessing the file directly by url**

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /n/sfck/SuiteCRM-7.10.4/cache/include/javascript/sugar_field_grp.js on this server.
Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe
```

**I have tried**

- Set permission of `SuiteCRM-7.10.4` folder to 755
- Disable all .htaccess file (Including the WordPress one)
- Create blank .htaccess file to `/cache/include/javascript`

**Notes**

- I have tried to move the conflicted file to the upper folder and it can be accessed normally (This problem only occurs in some folder).
- There's a WordPress installed on my site (not sure if this affected the installation).
- My site uses DirectAdmin.

Comment: Does it have a public url, can you give a link?

Comment: Yes, [here](http://phwt.me/SuiteCRM-7.10.4/cache/include/javascript/sugar_field_grp.js)

Comment: http://phwt.me/SuiteCRM-7.10.4/install.php - you need to install it first, have you done it?

Comment: I'm on the installation process [here](https://i.imgur.com/h6g700H.png). 403 error is popup when the page loaded and `YAHOO is not defined` error is popup on clicking next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `cache` folder seems to be not writable by webserver (as it should), make sure you've done:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data .   #or whoever else user your server use
sudo chmod -R 755 .
sudo chmod -R 775 cache custom modules themes data upload
sudo chmod 775 config_override.php 2>/dev/null
```

according to [SuiteCRM installation steps](https://docs.suitecrm.com/admin/installation-guide/downloading--installing/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer but sorry, I'm on a shared hosting using DirectAdmin. I don't think I can run these lines.

Comment: I don't see a problem to connect to shared hosting via ssh

Comment: In any case, the problem seems to be that your webserver have no ability to create `include/javascript/sugar_field_grp.js` - you just need to check if it's there. And check user/permissions for `cache` - webserver should be able to write there

Comment: You can check `cache` permissions with file manager in DirectAdmin -http://dhost.com/kb/how-to-use-file-manager-in-direct-admin-panel

Comment: File `sugar_field_grp.js` is already in SuiteCRM.zip file I downloaded and `cache` folder permission is already `776`

Comment: And owner/group is the same like your webserver (or as wordpress installation), right?

Comment: Yes, it's default from my hosting and only folder I change permission to 755 is `cache`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173678/discussion-between-alex-and-tacticalbacon).